# Why do the two surfaces seem to have a clear boundary even though they are the same color?

Tags: uv, texture-painting

I paint them in the same color, but they still look different:

[image]

Comment: I think we'll need to see your Blend file. You can share it via blend-exchange.com following the instructions there to copy the link to it and then edit your question and paste the link into it.

Comment: This illustration leaves me clueless.. could you provide a better one, which gives folks who have no experience of your project some context. please? (Indicating the 2 colours that are different, that you expect to be the same.) Are you using a material as reference while painting, or a single image?

Comment: Flat shading (or smooth shading with internal faces, custom split normals etc.), shadows, ambient occlusion, different materials ("Base color" is not the only property affecting resulting color), perhaps more nuances.

Comment: At first sight, that looks like inverted normals. Check face orientation.